# Handle stored procedure output parameter in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in mysql with a output parameter and i need to get the result to my php which is used codeigniter

The Register mode

```
  public function registerUser($data){

            $sql = "call register_new_user('" . $data['uemail'] . "','" . $data['fname'] . "','".$data['lname'] . "','" . $data['pword']."',
            '" . $data['states'] . "',".$data['chargifyId'].");";

            if ($query = $this->db->query($sql)) {

            return  $this->db->query("Select @last_id");               

            } else {
                return false;
            }

    }
```

and this is the stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `register_new_user`(IN `uemail` VARCHAR(100), IN `fname` VARCHAR(45),
IN `lname` VARCHAR(45), IN `pword` VARCHAR(100), IN `states` VARCHAR(20), IN `chargifyid` INT, OUT `last_id` INT)
    NO SQL
BEGIN

if not exists (SELECT * from gi_user where 
(gi_user_email = uemail)) THEN

INSERT INTO gi_user(gi_user_email, gi_user_fname, 
gi_user_lname, gi_user_password,gi_user_status, 
gi_account_id, chargifyId) 
VALUES (uemail,fname,lname,pword,states,1,chargifyid);

SET last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID( ) ;

END IF;


END
```

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: thanks for the response and i have add the model and the procedure

Comment: The second query isn't of use, try just getting the row from the first query $query->row() -- use print_r or var_dump to print out the result & test.

Answer (score 6):

use 
CodeIgniter Transactions

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

example:

```
$SQL = "call UPDATE("
                . $ID.","
                . $this->db->escape($data["NAME"])."," // input
                . $this->db->escape($data["DESCRIPTION"])."," // input
                . " @out1" ."," // output
                . " @out2" //output
                .");";


        $this->db->trans_start();
            $this->db->query($SQL); // not need to get output
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT @out1 as row_1,  @out2 as row_2");
        $this->db->trans_complete();

        $result = array();

        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
            $result = $query->result_array();

        print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$out='';
$query ="begin register_new_user('" . $email . "','" .$name. "','".$lname ."','". $pword."','" . $states . "',:out); end;";
    $stmt = oci_parse($this->db->conn_id, $query );
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":out", $out,300);

    oci_execute($stmt); 

    echo $out;
```

its working for me .

Answer (score 0):

Working Example!

--> SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE calculateStock
(IN itemId INT(10), OUT stock INT(10))
BEGIN
    DECLARE purchased INT(10);
    DECLARE sold INT(10);

    SET purchased = (SELECT SUM(purchase_rows.qty) AS purchased FROM purchase_rows WHERE template_id = item_id);
    SET sold = (SELECT SUM(sale_rows.qty) AS sold FROM sale_rows WHERE template_id = item_id);

    SET stock = purchased - sold; 
    SELECT stock;
END
```

--> Model

```
public function getStock($item_id){
    $query = "CALL calculateStock(?, @stock);";
    $parameters = array($item_id);

    $result = $this->db->query($query, $parameters);
    mysqli_next_result($this->db->conn_id); //Important Line 

    return $result->row()->stock;
}
```